# How to find path of Bridging-Header.h - Swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, bridging-header

Here I'm attaching a screenshot of created header file

I have created a new header file in xcode and named it as (projectname)-Bridging-Header.h. But I am not able to find the path and make it work. How to find the path of the file?

[image]

Comment: do drag and drop objective c file then automatic will be created header file. This time you can import and build or clean. I think you will get solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First go to project build setting,
2. Then search Swift in in the search box
3. After that you will find a **Objective C Bridging Header** option in **Swift Compiler Code Generation Area**
4. Add the **bridging header path** for this **Objective C Bridging Header Option**
5. Path should be Given as

Also you can find below the screen shot for the reference.

**[image: Project Name/Project Name Bridging Header.h]**

Comment: It's great bro @sukhdeep