# using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I have razor pay pod in my project for payment gateway and `SWRevelViewController` file for side bar controller. I selected the swift 5 and iOS version 13 and updated all the pods but still getting error

> error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5' pod 'TWMessageBarManager'
pod 'SwiftValidator', :git => 'https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator.git', :tag => '4.2.0'

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
pod 'DropDown'
pod 'MBRadioCheckboxButton'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
pod 'razorpay-pod', '~> 1.1.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'     
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.8.0'
pod "ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage"
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'PopupDialog', '~> 1.1'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'AppAuth','~> 1.2.0'
```

Comment: Please check your bridging header file path.

Comment: Ok I will check, is there any other issues

Comment: 99% i am sure, you didn't set properly, please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627382/10584330

Comment: I referred that answer but still, it's not working, same error, what can I do now?

Comment: Can i ask your Xcode version? And also make sure all pod files available in swift 5 or not because you selected swift 5 and For Xcode 11, you need to use CocoaPods 1.8.4 and nothing older.

Comment: it's Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29) and I am also using CocoaPods 1.8.4

Comment: Disable batch mode by adding a user-defined build setting named SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE and set it to NO. Go to your target's build settings and add this user-defined setting.

Comment: Ok, mam, I will check it and let you know, how it works

Comment: Yes pod swift version and try batch mode, if not working than let me know..!!

Comment: I added user-defined setting and set it to no but I am unable to add this in target

Comment: I have sent the screenshots on Linkedin

Comment: Remove from your bridging header file path : /Users/sjainmac/Downloads/TrippyCarApp7M20

Comment: ok I am going to check

Comment: I did, I removed extra lines but still, it's not working same error

Comment: whatever I am doing I am getting that same error again and again.

Comment: any update mam.

Comment: Yes i update you in linkedIn...! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your problem and as per you selected project language project work properly in **XCode 10.2** but you require changes for updated **XCode 11.2.1**

**Please follow few things :**

1. Make sure first your bridging header file path is proper in build settings.
2. You need to update razor pay pod because you add tag (pod 'razorpay-pod', '~> 1.1.1'), and pod updated in **Swift 5.1** **so please remove it and change pod name with `pod 'razorpay-pod'`**
3. Please change your build settings. **Set Build Library for Distribution** in the build settings for the target framework to **YES**.

**Hope it’s helpful to you.**

Comment: It works fine now, Thank you so much Anjali mam. I and dont have that much reputation yet your ans works, made my day. Thank you so much.

Comment: My header file has only 1 line ```#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"```. Is this correct?

Comment: That would be `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER`.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, i had to follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

```
config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'NO'
```

in my Podfile under

```
...

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Put it here (indent like this)
  ...
```

**Step 2**

- Select `Runner` on the left Panel
- Under `Targets`, select the target (usually "Runner")
- Select `Build Settings` from the top Menu
- Scroll down to `Build Options` and find the option "Build Libraries for Distribution"
- Set the value of "Build Libraries for Distribution" to `NO` (or set it for any particular build scheme)
- Clean Build Folder
- Delete flutter "build" folder, run `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get`

Comment: Thank you so much, but make sure to add "end" after target.build_configurations.each do |config| otherwise you got an error

Answer (score 1):

So I faced a problem with Razorpay swift version and following one of the suggested methodologies set Target>Build Libraries for Distribution to Yes.

Big mistake.

kept getting
`error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported`

Finally fixed it by setting Build Libraries for Distribution Back to No
[Razorpay issue was still not resolved so had to downgrade Flutter]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30426723)

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it in this way, Detailed steps are here, [Solution to Xcode Error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported](https://handyopinion.com/xcode-error-using-bridging-headers-with-module-interfaces-is-unsupported/)

Solution:

In your Project Level & Target level Build Settings tab, open the Build Options menu. And then set Build Libraries for Distribution option to No.

Comment: The accepted answer says to set it to **YES**. This is confusing..

Comment: Not a solution. Plus, you're posting a link to your own blog or whatever instead of answering the question in here.

Comment: It is not a solution as if you need to prepare the lib for distribution you need to have this option as YES