# Flutter - Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, bridging-header

I have a flutter project.
I am struggle to build IPA `flutter build ipa` due to:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported. 

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

This errors occurs during `Build target Runner` - `Planning target Runner` stage.

What's strange is that if I try to `archive` using `XCode` this error is displayed but the archive is correctly created.

I tried to make use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60733655/5619109) but I cannot get it right.
Where can I find build settings for the target framework?
What is target framework in my context?

My Set up:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 13.0.1
iOS Deployment Target: 13.0
XCode 14.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Proper way to solve this issue probably depends on your code (and most likely - dependencies). Without some more details about those more accurate answer might be impossible.

Ask yourself when did this error start to happening? What changes did you made? Which dependencies did you add and which did you update? (Version control history might be very helpful). Check issue trackers of those looking for related issues.

Some flutter packages require extra steps to be used on iOS. Some extra steps might be required only sometimes. For example [Awesome notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) packages has pretty straight forward installation process, but some extra steps are required if you want to use this package with the [Background Actions](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#-extra-ios-setup-for-background-actions). Also, don't forget to check FAQ and Common Known Issues - Awesome notifications plugin for example can give you "bridging headers" error and solution to fix this is given in [Common Known Issues](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#common-known-issues) section.

Answer (score 0):

For others that have the same problem. I solved this issue with setting "Build Libraries for Distribution" to "No" in XCode.