# Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging Headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

i am new to building ios apps using flutter, i have made sure i have setup the configuration for all packages for ios, but i still get this error, can anyone help,

P.S i am building using codemagic vnc, so my responses for possible fixes will not be immediate.

[image]

Attached is a picture with the complete error, thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer is in this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74243131/12453564