# Xcode : Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods, ipa

I'm trying to put my Flutter application in prep on AppleStore Connect via a Fastlane script.
During the ios build (pods), everything is ok, the connection to the store is done correctly and during the xcode build to create the archive to send to the store, I have an error "**error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported** " a little after the "**Running script 'Run Script'**" step.

Here the output :

```
[10:19:14]: ▸ Copying Pods-Runner-umbrella.h
[10:19:14]: ▸ Processing Pods-Runner-Info.plist
[10:19:14]: ▸ Compiling Pods-Runner-dummy.m
[10:19:14]: ▸ Compiling Pods_Runner_vers.c
[10:19:14]: ▸ Touching Pods_Runner.framework (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
[10:19:14]: ▸     Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[10:19:14]: ▸     Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[10:19:14]: ▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
[10:19:14]: ▸ Running script 'Run Script'
[10:20:23]: ▸ Copying GoogleService-Info.plist
[10:20:23]: ▸ Copying AppFrameworkInfo.plist
[10:20:23]: ▸ Compiling Main.storyboard
[10:20:26]: ▸ error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
[10:20:29]: ▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
[10:20:37]: ▸ ❌  error: Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[10:20:37]: ▸ Compiling AppDelegate.swift
[10:20:37]: ▸ Compiling GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m
[10:20:37]: ▸ Linking Runner
[10:20:37]: ▸ Processing Info.plist
[10:20:37]: ▸ Running script 'Run Script'
[10:20:37]: ▸ Generating 'Runner.app.dSYM'
[10:20:38]: ▸ Running script 'Thin Binary'
[10:20:39]: ▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
[10:20:41]: ▸ Running script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'
[10:20:42]: ▸     /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bvuyoqjrniposghabrdhstfdxmea/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/data/managed.json: Failed to parse executable: Invalid read request. startingAt: 0, offsetBy: 0, typeSize: 4 (UInt32), dataSize: 2
[10:20:45]: ▸ Touching Runner.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[10:20:46]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I just update flutter to 3.13.5 and some compatible packages, I launched my application on my phone and the app launches correctly, without errors in the logs.

I think my issue come from the build ipa :

```
Archiving com.myApp...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: [project number]
Running pod install...                                              4,5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        22,9s
Xcode archive done.                                         156,3s
Failed to build iOS app
```

---

My flutter doctor :

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
• Flutter version 3.13.5 on channel stable at /Documents/depot/Flutter/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 12fccda598 (2 weeks ago), 2023-09-19 13:56:11 -0700
• Engine revision bd986c5ed2
• Dart version 3.1.2
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 30.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = /Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14B47b
• CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.54.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

I tried to see the issue in my xcode build to have more details on the error.
The only result I got was : `SwiftDriver compilation error: com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler is not absolute` after my "Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported" issue.

I check some of help on github issue but there no match with my issue.

Comment: Update : There is a solution that works for me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629662/using-bridging-headers-with-module-interfaces-is-unsupported-command-compileswif